# Showing that matrix $A$ and linear operator $T: M_{n\times n} \rightarrow M_{n\times n}$ ($T(B) = AB$) have the same eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

$T: M_{n\times n} \rightarrow M_{n\times n} \\ T(B) = AB$

Defining $S_A$ as the set of eigenvalues of $A$ and $S_T$ as the set of eigenvalues of $T$, I have to prove $1. \ S_T \subseteq S_A$ and $2. \ S_A \subseteq S_T$.

The eigenvalues of $A$ are derived from the operation of $A$ on $n\times 1$ matrices but $T$ operates on $n\times n$ matrices and I don't think I can just assume $A$ to be the matrice form of $T$. I attempted defining an isomorphism $M_{n\times n} \rightarrow \mathbb{F}^{n^2}$ but clearly that wouldn't work because we can no longer use the same matrix multiplication anymore.

Comment: How do you justify $T(B) = AB = \lambda B = \lambda IB \Rightarrow det(A - \lambda I) = 0$ as $\det B$ can be equal to zero while $B \neq 0$?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net You are right! How did I even do that...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When $B$ has columns $b_1,b_2,\dots,b_n$ so that $B=(\ b_1\mid b_2 \mid \dots \mid b_n\ )$, then note that
$$
T(B) = AB = A(\ b_1\mid b_2 \mid \dots \mid b_n\ ) = (\ Ab_1\mid Ab_2 \mid \dots \mid Ab_n\ ).
$$

Hence $AB=\lambda B$ is equivalent to $Ab_i = \lambda b_i$ for all columns $b_i$ of $B$.

When $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, let $b\neq 0$ an eigenvector so that $Ab=\lambda b$ and consider the matrix $B=(\ b \mid b \mid \dots \mid b\ )$. We have $B\neq 0$ and
$$
AB = (\ Ab \mid Ab \mid \dots \mid Ab\ ) = (\ \lambda b \mid \lambda b \mid \dots \mid \lambda b\ ) = \lambda B.
$$
Hence $B$ is an eigenvector of $T$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$.

When $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $T$, so that $AB=\lambda B$ for some non-zero matrix $B$, there is at least one non-zero column $b_i$ of $B$ and for that we have $Ab_i = \lambda b_i$. Hence $b_i$ is an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$.

This shows that $A$ and $T$ have the same eigenvalues.